# Android: How to display changing variables?

Tags: java, android, textview

I have a problem with displaying sensors data on screen. I have class: SensorsData.class which have all needed data (all sensors results) and I want to display this data on screen in activity: SensorsActivity.class.

This is example of SensorsData.class (example of Light Sensor data):

```
public class SensorsData extends ContextWrapper implements EventListener, StepCounterListener, LinearAccListener, StepDetectorListener, LightSensorListener, PressureSensorListener, GravitySensorListener, RotationVectorListener, RelativeHumidityListener, ProximitySensorListener, TempSensorListener, AccelerometerSensorListener, GyroSensorListener, MagSensorListener {

    private LightSensor mLightSensor;


    public long accelx, accely, accelz, rotX, rotY, rotZ;
    public long magnX, magnY, magnZ, gravityX, gravityY, gravityZ;
    public long gyroX, gyroY, gyroZ, press, linaccelX, linaccelY, linaccelZ;
    public String temp, hum, step_detector;
    public int prox, light, step_counter;

    SensorsActivity cos;

    public SensorsData(Context base) {
        super(base);
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub

    }

    public void register(Context base) {

        mLightSensor = new LightSensor(getBaseContext());
        mLightSensor.setListener(SensorsData.this);

    }

    @Override
    public void onLightSensorChanged(int lux) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        cos.ustawiamyTextLight(lux);

    }
}
```

and SensorsActivity.class:

```
public class SensorsActivity extends Activity {

    private TextView lightText, pressureText, signText, noiseText, humidityText, linearAccText, proximityText, tempText, accelText, gyroText, magText, rotationText, gravityText, stepDetectorText, stepCounterText;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);  
        setContentView(R.layout.sensors);

        lightText = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.rLight);


        SensorsData sData = new SensorsData(getBaseContext());
        sData.register(getBaseContext()); 
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onStart();
    }

    public void ustawiamyTextLight(int lighttt) {
        lightText.setText("LIGHT level: " + lighttt + " lx");
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onStop();
    }

}
```

Variable "lighttt" is changed all the time, and i don;t know how to display it on screen, because now it doesn't work. Screen is black.